# @font-face working fine over localhost but NOT in AppHarbor

Tags: .net, css, hosting, font-face, appharbor

I am facing a problem while hosting my application over a AppHarbor.
I’ve a basic application over .net MVC 3.. In this application I’ve used the @font-face property to display content in custom fonts:

```
@font-face {
font-family: facefont;
src: url("raleway_thin.otf");
} 
body {    
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "facefont", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #696969;
}
```

When I run this application through my development server in loaclhost in works all fine with the content being shown in the custom font.
But when I pushed my webapp over AppHarbor here:

[testapp over AppHarbor](http://testapp-216.apphb.com/)

It’s no more showing the content in the custom font that I’ve used in .css . Am confused about it as am using same browser (Chrome 15.0) to view both but they are giving different results.

Kindly help.

---

I just worked out the this is happening only with the font files [*.otf, *.ttf].. I put an image in the same folder and its been added perfectly but again it failed to get the font file and displaying 404 over it.

---

Also done with configuring mimeTypes:

```
<staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
```

Comment: I checked out your paeg using Firebug, seems the font file hasn't been properly linked to, check your paths.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: Thnks fr replying, but its working fine here in my browser over localhost? and the path seems correct as the style sheet and the font file are in the same dir.

Comment: Check in Firebug or Chrome's developer tools. Firebug says there's an area in the 400-500 range of errors, usually is a 404.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: yeah u r rite its giving 404, bt the same path is given for the styleSheet and the font and both are in same dir, thn how it can find the .css but not the font .. ne idea plz? :s

Comment: In CSS the paths are relative to the CSS document's position. Try moving the font into another dir and changing the path accordingly.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: I just worked out the this is happening only with the font files [*.otf, *.ttf].. I put an image in the same folder and its been added perfectly but again the it failed to get the font file.

Comment: That's strange as *.ttf and *.otf files are supported filetypes. Ask your hosting company what the problem could be.

Comment: When I did hosting on a dedicated server, I had to add those filetype to mimetypes in IIS. How do we do that in AppHarbor? is the web.config solution working for you?

Comment: did you find a solution @Maven? I'm struggling to serve a .woff font using Appharbor..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your stylesheet is not in available at the location your page references it. This url serves up a 500: http://testapp-216.apphb.com/Content/Site.css

You should verify that AppHarbor deploys the relevant .css and font files. This is most easily done by downloading the build output package from AppHarbor and checking its content. If it's not there, you most likely need to set "Build Action" to "Content" in the project file reference.

It's also important that mimetypes are configured correctly.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Comment: oh this is a new problem jst with the latest build, its now not recognizing any .css and .js files.. let me try something to fix this up!

Comment: css problem solved its now linked, but the font issue still exists. kindly have a look.

Comment: Have you verified that the font file is indeed deployed to the server by AppHarbor?

Comment: how can i verify that? can u help a lil

Comment: You can download the build output from the build page on AppHarbor. This is what we deploy to application servers.

Answer (score 19):

In order get deploy ".woff" format fonts to Appharbor i had to do two things:

1: Include the font in my visual studio project, ensuring it's "Build" property was set to "Content" (as described above by @Korayem)
2: Add the follow config to Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the font file `.otf` is not served from the AppHarbor server as there is no MIME type configured specifying how to serve it.

See here how to add MIME types using Web.config: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

The MIME type you need to configure is `font/otf`

Something like:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
```

Comment: Thnx, can you brief me a lil about how can I configure MIME type specifying how to serve it?

Comment: no luck! ive updated my questions with the changes i made in Web.config but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file **Build Action** is set to **Content** in Visual Studio, other wise it won't be returned
[image: set build action to content]

Worked for me on AppHarbor

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet is located at /Content/Site.css and you are referencing your fonts in this file with "raleway_thin.otf" which is relative to the CSS file. Therefore it is expecting this file path to exist /Content/raleway_thin.otf

I'm not familiar with appharbour, but make sure all your files are case sensitive (i.e. causes windows to unix/linux issues).

Otherwise, does the web server prevent certain file extensions from being loaded from the directory in question. On apache you can tell it which file types are allowed to be used in a directory.

Having said that 404 means your URL http://testapp-216.apphb.com/Content/raleway_thin.otf does not exist

Comment: yea font was in the same dir 'Content' ive changed it now to see something happens bt its still stuck. `src: url("font/raleway_thin.otf");`

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement  @Lloyd solution ..
2. It is recommended to add all font related files to mime types not just .woff

ref. http://geekswithblogs.net/JayantSharma/archive/2012/08/26/adding-mimetype-in-web.conifg-for-html5.aspx